# R: Extract value from column 1 to column 2 based on column 3

Tags: r

I have the following problem: I want to create a column in my dataset which contains values from an already existing column, based on a third column.

Example:

```
a <- sample(1:3, 20, T)
b <- sample(1:100, 20, T)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I now want to create a column c in the data frame that contains the value from b for every row where a == 1 and 0 if-else. I know this should be easy to do, but I somehow only got it to work with a complicated solution creating a new data frame and then binding it to the original one..

Comment: Use: `df$c <- ifelse(df$a == 1, df$b, 0)`

Comment: Or `df$c <- df$b * (df$a == 1)`